# I/O Bound Process and Thread Priority

Tags: multithreading, io, windows-services, cpu-usage

I have a Windows Service that runs 20 threads. Each thread manages a remote device. The threads basically just access database (SQL Server) and send and receive messages through TCP/IP. No fancy algorithm or heavy processing. This process is taking 80% in a 8-core CPU with lots of memory.

I didn't run a profiler on this service but I've seen the code million of times... It's just a while loop with a sleep of 500ms at the end of the loop. So the code inside the loop is executed only 2 or less times in 1 second time frame.

I was wondering if the process is I/O bound, why such this heavy CPU utilization? What if I lower the process priority?

Comment: "I didn't run a profiler".  Do you want *us* to run it for you?

Comment: We cannot know the answer because we know nothing about your code. If you don't have a profiler handy: Pause the debugger 10 times. Where does it stop most?

Comment: Well... I didn't run a profiler because I couldn't. Anyways... I was just asking more of a theoretical question. I am asking if I can lower the process priority so the process consumes less CPU...